# Separate from Serial for digitalWrite()

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

This is my current code (Arduino Mega 2560):

```
#define p1 2
#define p2 3

void setup() {
 pinMode(p1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(p2, OUTPUT);
 Serial.println("ARDUINO : CONNECTED");
}

void loop() {
 if (Serial.available()) {
  String state = Serial.readString();
  
  if (state.startsWith("LED1ON")) {
    digitalWrite(p1, HIGH);
  }
  if (state.startsWith("LED1OFF")) {
    digitalWrite(p1, LOW);
  }
  if (state.startsWith("LED2ON")) {
    digitalWrite(p2, HIGH);
  }
  if (state.startsWith("LED2OFF")) {
    digitalWrite(p2, HIGH);
  }
  // ... and next condition LED
 }
}
```

how can i do for multiple input serial use seperator(";") ? like : LED1ON;LED2OFF

expacted:
one time command (LED1ON;LED2OFF) many condition (led turn on and led 2 turn off)

please, tks

Comment: This sounds like homework and the point of the homework is to learn parsing. And the delineation character is a semicolon.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes bro, using delimiter ; for command multiple condition. help me

Answer (score 2):

You might want to get used to visit [the Arduino library reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/) to learn what is possible and how to use it.

For your case, you are interested in the method [`readStringUntil()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstringuntil/).

The reading, understanding, experimenting, debugging, and finishing is left as an exercise to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Consider refactoring your code such that you read in strings then search through the string character by character copying each character to a new string until you find a semicolon.  When this happens do not copy the semicolon.  Instead execute the existing "if" statements to turn on / off the LEDs based on the content of the new string.  When done, erase the new string, loop back and continue to copy characters to the new string until the next semicolon.  If there is no more data to be copied, read in more data until data is unavailable.

Comment: There is a quicker way in C++ to parse through a string based on a given delineating character.  But it abstracts you from what is really going on.  Which is likely what is outlined in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[readString](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/) reads from Serial until it times out. This means it might undershoot or overshoot both the end of the line (if there is one) or the semicolon.

I suggest reading into a `char` buffer (say, of 30 bytes length) until either a newline or semicolon is reached. Then terminate the buffer with 0x00 (to make it a proper "C" string) and then do a simple string compare (`strcmp`).